# Failed to start dotTrace profiling on Windows Server 2012 R2

Tags: installation, jetbrains-ide, dottrace

We are trying to run dotTrace on production server but it's failing. We tried after reboot also but didn't work.

[image]

dotTrace: https://www.jetbrains.com/profiler/

OS: Windows Server 2012 R2

System type: 64 bit

This is IIS application and we are trying to attach w3wp.exe worker process to dotTrace.

[image]

We have NewRelic Status monitor on this machine.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solutions in this article 
https://dotnettools-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360000115090-Failed-to-start-dot-trace-profiling-on-Windows-Server-2012-R2?page=1#community_comment_360000119684